# No, minSdk(API 15) > deviceSdk(API1) in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am a newbie in android development. Yesterday, I have setup my environment in windows 8, I have downloaded android SDK, when i run it, asked me to install some tools. I have installed all. After that i tried creating a sample project, then I run it on my phone connecting with USB. I am succeed in windows.

But, Now I tried to connect to my android studio in linux mint. I am getting error as No minSDK, and also I went to the sdk folder and opened terminal and run like this

```
adb devices
```

- daemon started successfully *
  ZL2GLMA5A0811781    no permissions

That is the output... Please help me out...

EDIT:

I have enabled developer options and also USB debugging. As I mentioned already, it worked well on windows 8 with IntelliJ but in android studio,linux mint it's not working...

Comment: maybe this will be helpfull http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/888

Comment: I will try, currently I am away from that laptop... will confirm you after I tried...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set up your linux mint system to detect your device.

If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a `udev` rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development.

In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the `ATTR{idVendor}` property.

For a list of vendor IDs, see [USB Vendor IDs](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds), below.

To set up device detection on Linux follow these steps:

**Step 1:**

Log in as root and create this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

Use this format to add each vendor to the file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

In this example, the vendor ID is for `HTC`. The `MODE` assignment specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group owns the device node.You can find vendor ID in above link.

**Step 2:**

Now execute:

```
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

For detailed information please check [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) and [this](http://ptspts.blogspot.in/2011/10/how-to-fix-adb-no-permissions-error-on.html).

Disconnect the USB cable between the phone and the computer.

Reconnect the phone.

Run **`adb devices`** to confirm that now it has permission to access the phone.

if above steps doesn't work for you then  kill and start the adb server again. On linux: `sudo adb kill-server` and then `sudo adb start-server`. Then it will detect nearly every device out of the box.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Solution->End process adb.exe from Task manager

process->
1)Press ctrl+shift+Esc (to open task manager)
2)now click on processes tab
3)click on adb.exe
4)click on End process

Now run your application

still not working do above process 2-3 times..

Thats it..!!

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed the right Android SDK. Go to Tools-> Android-> SDK manager

Then select SDK as per phone android version.

You will have to rebuild